# Reading/Appending Server-Side CSV Files in MVC/Razor

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, csv, razor

So, I'm a newbie using MVC and Razor - I do have some C# experience, however.
That being said, I need to make a simple web-app and the project specifications require server-side data to be stored in CSV.  Everything I've researched online involves uploading a CSV file to the server, or letting the user download one.  *This is not what I want*.

This is what I need help with:

1) Appending a new line to an existing server-side CSV file between user page directs/requests.

User submits page --> server appends data to server-side CSV --> User gets redirected to new page

2) Iterating through a static CSV file and presenting the data in a table.

User requests page --> Server iterates through CSV and dumps line data into a table --> User gets page with table full of data

Any ideas where to start with this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. Decide where you want to store the file, here is one of the paths:
   string csvPath = Path.Combine(HttpContext.Current.Request.PhysicalApplicationPath, "App_data") + "\info.csv";
2. In the controller action use regular File IO APIs (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.file(v=vs.110).aspx) to manipulate the file

While this may answer your specific question, this wouldn't scale when you have many front ends, multiple users trying out your site,...  Suggest going with a backend DB to store such info.  You would need to use locks solve the latter if you are not going to use DB.

Comment: I think this will work perfectly - the client isn't worried about scalability, and that this project will be incredibly low-traffic (their call, not mine).  This will help immensely.

Comment: Once again thank you for the answer.  This provided the necessary basis for me to get my work done; basically did exactly what you did and works splendidly.